# Trying to fit a response surface with R's formula notation

Tags: r, regression, formula, polynomials, coefficients

I have a set of a couple of dozen numeric variables and am trying to figure out how to compactly express a quadratic form in those variables. I also want to include the variables themselves. The idea here is that we are fitting a response surface, rather than interacting a group of treatments, as the standard R formula notation seems to assume. I am trying to get appropriate expressions turned into an R formula, suitable for estimation by different techniques, with different data sets, or over different periods.

If there is an explicit statement of how R's formula notation works, anywhere, I have not been able to find it. There is an ancient paper from which R supposedly copied the notation, but it is by no means identical to current R usage. Every other description I have found just gives examples, that do not cover every case -- not even close to every case.

So, just as an example, here I try to construct a quadratic form in three variables, without writing out all the pairs by hand with an `I()` around each pair.

```
library(tidyverse)
A <- B <- C <- 1:10
LHS <- 1:10 * 600
tb <- tibble(LHS, A, B, C)
my_eq <- as.formula(LHS ~ I(A + B + C)*I(A + B + C))
```

I have not found any way to tell if I have succeded 
Neither 
`my_form_eq`  nor

```
terms(my_form_eq)
```

seem at all enlightening.

For example, can one predict whether

`identical(as.formula(LHS ~ I(A + B + C)*I(A + B + C)), as.formula(LHS ~ I((A + B + C)*(A + B + C)))`

is true or false? I can not even guess. Or to take an even simpler case, is `~ A * I(A)` equal to A, `I(A^2)`, or something else? And how would you know?

To restate my question, I would like either a full statement of how R's formula notation works, adequate to cover every case and predict what each would mean, or, failing that, a straightforward way of producing an expansion of any existing formula into all the atomic terms for which coefficients will be estimated.

Answer (score 0):

This may not answer your question, but I'll post this anyway since I think it may help a little.

The `I` function inhibits the interpretation of operators such as "+", so your formula is probably not going to do what you expect it to do. For example, the results of `lm(my_eq)` will be the same as the results of doing the following:

```
D <- A + B + C
lm(LHS ~ D * D)
```

And then you may as well just do `lm(LHS ~ D)`.

For your question, I believe John Maindonald wrote a good book that explains R formulas for many situations. But it's in my office and today is a Sunday.

Edit: For the expansion, I believe you have to fit the model and then look at the call or the terms:

```
> my_eq <- as.formula(LHS ~ (A + B + C) * (A + B + C))
> my_formula <- lm(my_eq)
> attr(terms(my_formula), "term.labels")
[1] "A"   "B"   "C"   "A:B" "A:C" "B:C"
```